TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
I am now trying to use addLiquidity with Uniswap V2 on sepolia testnet.
I am using web3.js in truffle, but there are some areas where errors keep occurring.
I have posted only the necessary code here.
import routerArtifact from "@uniswap/v2-periphery/build/UniswapV2Router02.json" assert {type: "json"};

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/~~"));

const routerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      routerArtifact.abi,
      routerAddress
    )
    
    
    
const addLiquidityTx = routerContract.methods.addLiquidity(
      token0Address,
      token1Address,
      token0Amount,
      token1Amount,
      0,
      0,
      toAddress,
      deadline
    ).encodeABI();

console.log("add:", addLiquidityTx);


 const tx = {
      from: _from,
      to: routerAddress,
      gas: 50000,
      gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
      data: addLiquidityTx
    }

    const signature = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
    console.log("sig:", signature);
    
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signature.rawTransaction).on(
      "receipt", (receipt)=>{
        console.log(receipt);
      }
    )

If you write and run the above, you will receive the following results and errors.
add: 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
sig: {
  messageHash: '0x6d37bee0dd7b07850a73273e4b475186493054dcb864c34d659105dc53b812af',
  v: '0x1546d71',
  r: '0x26276f65c2b651e220cfdf78cfcc49099d83692f0e7c383334b3d692644845a2',
  s: '0x21f88625ebc0dc9d7b81d951145465e26cb498d20f09a41ea10760401dfb8b6c',
  rawTransaction: '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',
  transactionHash: '0x48077c0a1b368a7c006138ee7420db756199f9a08b576ceb0e30b4ec07de0f35'
}

file:///home/yujinsong/BlockchainSC/Ethereum/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/esm/utils/get_transaction_error.js:54
            error = new TransactionRevertInstructionError(_reason.reason, _reason.signature, transactionReceiptFormatted, _reason.data);
                    ^

TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
    at file:///home/Ethereum/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/esm/utils/get_transaction_error.js:54:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at file:///home/Ethereum/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/esm/utils/get_transaction_error.js:23:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (file:///home/Ethereum/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/esm/utils/get_transaction_error.js:19:12)
    at getTransactionError (file:///home/Ethereum/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/esm/utils/get_transaction_error.js:30:12)
    at SendTxHelper.<anonymous> (file:///home/Ethereum/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/esm/utils/send_tx_helper.js:75:33)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (file:///home/Ethereum/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/esm/utils/send_tx_helper.js:4:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: undefined,
  reason: 'execution reverted',
  signature: undefined,
  receipt: undefined,
  data: undefined,
  code: 402
}


What's the problem!?
What's the problem!? I think the gas setting was wrong, so I set the gas value to 32550, but 'out of gas' appeared as the cause of the error. So I increased the gas value to 32551 and ran it again, and 'execution reverted' appeared as the cause of the error. What could be the cause? How can I solve this? Please help me.

This is my package.json file.
"dependencies": {
"@beandao/contracts": "^0.8.0",
"@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.9.3",
"@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.1.15",
"@uniswap/v2-core": "^1.0.1",
"@uniswap/v2-periphery": "^1.1.0-beta.0",
"dotenv": "^16.4.5",
"ethers": "^6.7.1",
"truffle-flatten": "^1.0.8",
"web3": "^4.9.0",
"web3-core": "^4.4.0",
"web3-eth-accounts": "^4.1.2",
"web3-eth-contract": "^4.5.0"
},
"type": "module"

Try using more gas. 50k may be enough for a token transfer but not for a more complex contract. You can try in a test network using 1M for gas then reduce looking at the gas used for the transaction.

I had the same exact issue, the way I fixed it was by not using the web3.js library, but rather switching to ethers.js 6.7.1. Probably not what you are looking for, but that was my way of bypassing the issue.
async function setValue(deployedContractAbi, deployedContractAddress){
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(host);
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(accountPrivateKey, provider);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(deployedContractAddress, deployedContractAbi, provider);
    const contractWithSigner = contract.connect(wallet);
    const tx = await contractWithSigner.set(value);
    await tx.wait();
    return tx;
  }

